# How to have embedded requests in a firestore query within react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-firebase-hooks

In a firebase database, I've a collection of households. For each household, I've a sub-collection "invites". Not an "map" of object, but a real sub-collection.

In one page, I'm trying to retrieve each household, and I need to have each invite included in my household.

Then on my page, I will two embedded map to display each household and their related invites.

For now, the closest way I came up with was to make a "useEffect":

```
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  const householdsRef = collection(db, "households");
  const queryRef = query(
    householdsRef,
    where("participantsIds", "array-contains", user!.uid)
  );

  const collectionRef = queryRef.withConverter(householdConverter);
  const [households, householdLoading, householdError, householdSnapshot] =
    useCollectionData<Household>(collectionRef);
  const [householdWithInvites, setHouseholdWithInvites] = useState<Household>();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (households) {
      const newHouseholds = households.map((household) => {
        const invitesRef = collection(
          db,
          "households",
          household.id,
          "invites"
        );
        const [invites] = useCollection(invitesRef);
        const inviteData = invites?.docs.map((d) => d.data as any) as string[];
        return { ...household, invites: inviteData } as Household;
      });
      console.log(newHouseholds);
    }
  }, households);
```

But I get this error:

> react-router-dom.js?v=46f739bb:3297 React Router caught the following error during render Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:\
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

(I'm using `react-firebase-hooks` for those wondering where the useCollection are coming from).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

is telling you that you can't use a hook anywhere other than immediately inside a component function. This is rule #1 in the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) that you also see cited in the error message. Anywhere else is an error.

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

This has nothing to do with Firestore and its query.  It is just about React hooks.

You have a call to the hook `useCollection` inside a `useEffect` hook. That's not valid. Try moving the `useCollection` elsewhere, such as in the component hook along with the other `useCollection` you have there. Or, simply don't use `useCollection` at all for the followup queries since React doesn't support non-deterministic use of hooks (because of the rules of hooks). You can [perform a Firestore query using the normal API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) if you want, but you can't use useCollection there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, my question is more about how to query subcollection not why the react hook approach didn't work, the hook was just a desperate tentative. Can you tell me how to do so?

Comment: Why don't you fix the error message first, then post a new question that more accurately describes the problem with the query itself, free of other problems? As I said, the error message has nothing to do with Firestore. That error could be preventing anything at all from happening with Firestore as you might expect.

Comment: Also consider maybe not using useCollection at all for the followup queries and instead just make them without a Firestore hook so you can avoid the error. React doesn't support non-deterministic hooks, as you can tell from the rules of hooks.

Comment: Apparently, it's the approach that's wrong. I've no idea how to embbed a hook call in another hook enumeration result.  You're not helping at all...

Comment: My answer is saying that you can't do it (and so is React).  It's not allowed, and you can't force it or work around it because of the rules of hooks. So, don't use useCollection inside a hook, just do a [normal query using the Firestore API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) if you need to do it inside a hook.

Comment: But it's the `react-firebase-hooks` manages the real-time update, right? So it means I will loose the real-time update(or have to implement something myself and have the same issue I currently have). I don't see how I could have an `onSnapshot` inside a loop of another list that is also async. Can you share an example, I can't find any, and honestly, I'm so frustrated by this that I'm considering ditching firebase to use my own backend, I don't know if I don't have the correct wording, but I really can't find similar example.

Comment: If you need multiple non-deterministic realtime listeners, then you can't use hooks.  You will have to instead use the old class-based style components where you control exactly what happens on mount and unmount where you are no longer bound by the rules of hooks.  You will also have to manage the addition and removal of listeners manually.